# Implement angular 2 formly for file upload?

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-formly, input-type-file

I need to create dynamic form in angular 2. for that I am using angular formly. but it doesnt have any example for input type 'file' upload. Does someone has already implemented this?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented custom file type based on ngx-formly documentation maybe that could be of help.

I know it's way to late but someone looking for answers may get some help with this :D

https://stackblitz.com/edit/formly-file-type-multiple-demo?file=src/app/file-type.component.scss

Answer (score 0):

formly provide a bunch of examples on their demo, for input type 'file' upload check the following link: https://formly.dev/examples/other/input-file